# Getting row values to columns in SQL server select query

Tags: sql-server-2008, rows

I am working on ans SQL server database, to bring the result in a specific format. I have the data in the table as

```
Category      AmountType       EligibleAmount  NonEligibleAmount

 100              FA               1500.00       1200.00
 100              IA               2000.00       1300.00
 200              FA               1000.00        800.00
 200              IA               3500.00       2100.00
```

I want the output to be as

```
Category  FA EligibleAmt  FA NonEligibleAmt  IA EligibleAmt   IA NonEligibleAmt  

 100        1500.00          1200.00              2000.00        1300.00
 200        1000.00           800.00              3500.00        2100.00
```

There could be only two rows for a category in the table at any point of time.Could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: If you don't care which row you get for each category, you could just use `GROUP BY` in your select. Check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for `GROUP BY`

Comment: I don't want to group the rows, then I have to sum the amount values which I don't want to do. I want to bring the second row amount values in column format.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AMOUNTTYPE = 'FA' THEN ELIGIBLEAMOUNT END) AS [FA ELIGIBLE], 
                 MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AMOUNTTYPE = 'FA' THEN NONELIGIBLEAMOUNT END) AS [FA NON ELIGIBLE], 
                 MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AMOUNTTYPE = 'IA' THEN ELIGIBLEAMOUNT END) AS [IA ELIGIBLE], 
                 MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AMOUNTTYPE = 'IA' THEN NONELIGIBLEAMOUNT END) AS [IA NON ELIGIBLE]
FROM  dbo.TESTTABLE
GROUP BY CATEGORY
```